# How to overwrite print and println in processing.js?

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I'm using processing.js 1.4.1 and have code like this:

```
new Processing($('canvas')[0], $('texarea').val());
```

How can I overwrite print function (without modifing the code of the library) so it display output in `$('pre')`?

I can overwrite `Processing.logger` (which is used by println in line 4404) but then print don't work until I run println and there is no `Processing.println` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can compile and run the processing code by myself, and instance of processing object have print and println method (as well as all processing functions):

```
var sketch = Processing.compile(texarea.val());
var processing = new Processing(canvas[0]);

processing.print = function(str) { output.append('<span>' + str + '</span>'); };
processing.println = function(str) { processing.print(str + '\n'); };

sketch.attach(processing, Processing.prototype); // defaultScope is set to the Processing.prototype
sketch.onLoad(processing);
if (processing.setup) {
    processing.setup();
    processing.resetMatrix();
    sketch.onSetup();
}
if (processing.draw) {
    processing.redraw();
}
```

the code don't handle loops it was based on line 8514

```
var executeSketch = function(processing) {
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an explanation here how to do it here: http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html#interface.
It requires you to bind javascript to Processing sketch in order to call its functions.

This fiddle probably explains better than describing it would:
http://jsfiddle.net/98AsE/

My solution required the javascript method to be a property of 'javascript' object (`this` in global namespace) in order to work, otherwise Processing wouldn't see it:

```
this.displayMsg = function(msg){
    document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML += msg;
}
```

After that, overwriting `print` and `println` should be easy.

Comment: Little but of a mess, can it be done without code in processing, only in javascript?